# There is a "code" for language (English, Spanish, etc...) not defined?

Tags: iso, identification

In my application there is language detection. Languages have some identification code like *en* for English, *pt* for Portuguese, *fr* for French, etc.

Is there a language code for the case when a language cannot be identified (unknown language)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language codes you're using look like ISO 639-1. There is no ISO 639-1 code for an indeterminate or unknown language; however, "xx" could be used as as a reasonable placeholder.

Answer (score 8):

If your system allows for three-letter codes, the [ISO 639-2 standard](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/faq.html#25) says:

> If there is language content, but the specific language cannot be
>   determined, a special identifier is provided by ISO 639-2:
>
> **und** (**Undetermined**)

Comment: fun fact: in the german language, [und](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/und) means "and"

Answer (score 1):

You probably know it already, but at least for the benefit of others who may look your question up later:

In C, C++ and Unix/Linux generally, and sometimes elsewhere, there is something that goes by the cryptic name of "the C locale."  This is really the absence of a *locale,* which is to say, the absence of a set of language- and country-related conventions.  In the C locale, text is sorted in straight character-code (usually ASCII) order, which means that "ABC" precedes "XYZ" precedes "abc" precedes "xyz."

One needn't specify any code at all to get the C locale.  It has no code -- a significant fact which is at least tangentially related to your question.